# facebook js sdk login not working

Tags: facebook, oauth, permissions

i have an app
as admin, everything works
as a tester user - none!

my code is:

var fbAsyncInit = function() {

```
    FB.init({
        appId  : [APP_ID],
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true,
        oauth  : true
    });


FB.login(function(response)
{
    if (response.session)
    {
        if (response.perms)
        {
            alert('user is logged in and granted some permissions: ' + response.perms);
        }
        else
        {
            alert('logged in but didnt grant permissions');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert('not logged in');
    }
},
{scope:'publish_stream'});
```

}
the console log response is:

```
Object {authResponse: undefined, status: "not_authorized"}
```

and the tester user is always get the not logged in alert

i really don't know what to do with the setting so it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling FB.Login through onclick event. i.e put FB.login inside some javascript function and call that function onclick of some button. Direct call to FB.login would be blocked by pop up blocker.